# How to make Eclipse system jobs visible in the progress monitor?

Tags: eclipse, pde

Eclipse distinguishes between [regular and system jobs](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/runtime_jobs_progress.htm).
First are shown in the progress monitor (bottom right) of eclipse, the latter not.

Is there a configuration option to see also the system jobs in the progress monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them visible in the Progress View (look under the view menu). I don't think there's a way to make them visible on the status bar.